# Simple Hello World using Angularjs components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-components

This is my first attempt at angularJs components so please have patience. Any ideas why it would not print Hello World?

http://plnkr.co/edit/D3DMVAaechJUj4ZzPBDL?p=preview

script.js

```
(function () {

  'use strict';

    angular
         .module('myApp', [])
         .component('sampleComponent', {
             template: '<h1>Hello {{$ctrl.name}}!</h1>',
             bindings: {
                 name: '<'
             },
             controller: function () {
               //alert('here');
             }
         });

})();
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
     <sample-component name="World"></sample-component>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `'<'` for your binding. This means that when passing `name="World"`, `World` is supposed to be an Angular expression, whose value is passed to the component. Since you have no `World` variable in the root scope, it's undefined, and an empty string is thus displayed.

Use `'@'` for your binding, or use `name="'World'"`.